# vim: stop xml validation when I save file

Tags: xml, vim, dtd

Every time I save an xml file (often a maven pom file) in vim it reports this error:

```
(1 of 1) error: Validation failed: no DTD found !
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

This is annoying. I'd like to tell vim to stop validating xml files on save but I'm open to other solutions. The error seems to be coming from xmllint but fiddling with the xmllint.vim file has no effect.

Comment: Vim doesn't validate anything if you don't instruct it to do so. What ftplugin do you have? Plugins? What's in your vimrc?

Comment: It was the eclim plugin. It wasn't installed with the rest of my plugins because it comes with it's own installer so I missed it. Thanks for the response. Should I delete this post or simply update the question with the answer?

Comment: Just add an answer yourself if you can with your "level", otherwise update the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out to be the eclim plugin doing the validate.